# functions of bounded variation and gradient vector measure

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove a function of bounded variation on some domain $D\subset R^n$, $f\in BV(D)$, has the property that there is a constant $C$, such that 
$$
  \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{C}{r^{n+1}} \int_{D\times D} 1_{\|x-y\|\leq r} |f(x)-f(y)| d\mu_x d\mu_y = |f|_{BV}
$$
In this formula, measure $\mu$ is the uniform probability measure on $D$. This is equivalent to prove that the measure
$$
 \frac{C}{r^{n+1}} \int_{D} 1_{\|x-y\|\leq r} |f(x)-f(y)| d\mu_y 
$$
weakly converges to the Radon measure $|\nabla f|$, the total variation measure of finite Radon vector measure $\nabla f$ when $r\rightarrow 0$. This is easy to see when $f$ is smooth, by using an easy Taylor expansion, but it is not so easy here as we need a similar Taylor expansion in the distributional sense. Any reference about this topic?

Answer (score 3):

The property is proved in the litterature (together with its $W^{1, p}$ counterpart):

Augusto C. Ponce, *A new approach to Sobolev spaces and connections to Γ-convergence*, Calc. Var. Partial Differential Equations **19** (2004), no. 3, 229–255, DOI: 10.1007/s00526-003-0195-z.

Jean Van Schaftingen, Michel Willem, *Set transformations, symmetrizations and isoperimetric inequalities* in *Nonlinear analysis and applications to physical sciences*, 135–152, Springer Italia, Milan, 2004.

The result for $W^{1, p}$ was already known.

Jean Bourgain, Haïm Brezis, Petru Mironescu, *Another look at Sobolev spaces*, in Menaldi, J.L., et al. (eds.), *Optimal control and partial differential equations*, 439–455, IOS Press, 2001.